# What are "depression regions" in heuristic searches?

Tags: search, artificial-intelligence, heuristics

While reading about weighted heuristic searches, I came to know that they don't perform well in depression regions; what *are* "depression regions"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [this paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~maxim/files/mha_rss14.pdf), *Multi-Heuristic A** (Aine *et al.*, 2014), "depression regions" can be defined as:

> ...regions in the search space
>   where the correlation between the heuristic values and the
>   actual cost of the path to goal is weak

The related references are:

- C. Hernandez and J. A. Baier. Avoiding and Escaping Depressions in Real-Time Heuristic Search. *J. Artif. Intell. Res. (JAIR)*, 43:523–570, 2012. [[Link](https://www.jair.org/media/3590/live-3590-6238-jair.pdf)]
- C. M. Wilt and W. Ruml. When Does Weighted A* Fail? In *SOCS*. AAAI Press, 2012. [[Link](http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/SOCS/SOCS12/paper/viewFile/5413/5187)]

The former provides a similar definition:

> ...bounded areas of the search space in which the heuristic function is inaccurate compared to the actual cost to reach a solution.